# Ruby framebuffer on Raspberry

Tags: ruby, framebuffer

I want to write on framebuffers on a Raspberry Pi. I have to use Ruby but I didn't find any library. Is there any library like pygame for Ruby that I can use on Raspberry ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered RubySDL?

https://ohai.github.io/rubysdl/

It requires an extra layer, but SDL has been a linux mainstay for a while now. Also, according to this thread, it has a display mode that doesn't require X, although it's not framebuffer per se. (Kind of stretching the question here, but I figure they're comparable enough it counts.)

https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=40155#40155

Beyond that, I don't really have a lot of experience with SDL. My understanding, however, is that it's very similar to PyGame and friends.